# Regular module endomorphisms into itself

Tags: representation-theory, modules, algebras

Let $k$ be a field and let $A$ be an algebra over $k$. Denote by $End_A (A)$ the set of all endomorphisms of the regular $A$-module $A$ into itself. Fix $a \in A$, and define the A-module homomorphism $r_a : A \rightarrow A$ by $r_a(x) = x \cdot a$.

Clearly, $\{r_a: a \in A\} \subseteq End_A (A)$. But, is it true that moreover $\{r_a: a \in A\} = End_A (A)$? If so, how to show this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: An $A$-module endomorphism is determined by where it sends $1\in A$.

Comment: Almost there, but it turns out that if $r_a(1)=1$, then $1 \cdot a = 1$, which is confusing.

Comment: @mikrez: Yes. Why would that be confusing?

Comment: Okay then, if some $\varphi \in End_A (A)$ sends $1$ to some $a\in A$, i.e. $\varphi(1)=a=1 \cdot a = r_a(1)$.

Comment: That is not a complete thought. One writes "if $\varphi\in{\rm End}_AA$ sends $1\mapsto a\in A$ then $\varphi(x)=x\varphi(1)=xa=r_a(x)$ for all $x\in A$, hence $\varphi=r_{\varphi(1)}$. As was said, the endomorphism is *determined* (in the sense that *all* of its values are determined) by where $1$ is sent to. In this way we show every endomorphism is a right multiplication. Was my answer not useful?

Comment: It is fine, thank you, I just already showed that.